# Minimum Processor required?

Tags: configuration, windows

I have an older computer I'd like to set Tor up on, but I'm trying to figure out if its Intel Pentium 2 will support it. I have 2GB of RAM, XP SP3, adequate graphic/audio cards, etc. I' just like to know if an Intel Pentium 2 will run it, and if so, will I get any notable issues?

Comment: Please provide more information. What particular processor do you have, what clock speed is it running at, how much cache does it have, etc.?

Comment: I said Intel Pentium 2 in the first sentence :)

Comment: There are lots of processors with various specs in the Pentium II range (though I suspect any of them are fine).

Comment: @Timtech Should this be client only? (in which case I'd say there's no problem or more information required, otherwise....)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there should be nothing preventing Tor from running on a Windows XP box with a Pentium 2 class CPU, and your system has more than sufficient RAM for most use cases (Quite a few people run Tor successfully on the Raspberry Pi).

However:

- Windows XP is approaching End of Life, and it is unknown how long the Tor Project will continue to support Windows XP past that date  (Using a operating system that is no longer getting security updates is suboptimal in general).
- The developers are in the process of incorporating a better optimized Curve25519 implementation that requires SSE2.  Once this code is in official builds, you will need to compile your own copy of Tor (See [#8897](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/8897)).